# Best way to create child class from a abstract Base class

Tags: delphi, polymorphism, abstract-class, delphi-xe3

Best way to create child class from a abstract Base class.

In my project I have a base class abstract and two child class in this way.

```
TbaseClass=class
public
    procedure Doit;virtual;abstract;
    procedure Calculate;virtual;abstract;


Tchild1class=class(TbaseClass)
..
protected
    procedure CalcArea;virtual;
public
    procedure Doit;override;
    procedure Calculate;override;


Tchild2class=class(Tchild1class)
protected
    procedure CalcArea;override;
```

In my buttonclick code I create the needed childclass in this way, and is working.

```
.....
var
 T:TBaseClass;
begin
    case OP of
    1: T:=Tchild1class.Create;
    2: T:=TChild2Class.Create;
T.Doit;
T.Calculate;
end;
```

My question is the next.
I can make a constructor create procedure in my base abstract class , that depending of int parameter generate the needed child class???
For Example:

```
constructor TBaseClass.Create(OP:integer);
begin
inherited;
case OP of
    1: Tchild1class.Create; ///>>>???
    2: TChild2Class.Create; //>>>>???
end;
```

It's this possible?.

What is the best way to doit this?.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Once a constructor has begun running, the class of object being created is fixed. An object cannot change its class, not even during construction.

You can write a *factory function* that takes the integer parameter and chooses which descendant class to instantiate. It would be a lot like your proposed invalid constructor, just as a standalone function or class method instead of a constructor.

You could also write a function that just returns the *class*, and then you can instantiate it afterward, like this:

```
type
  TBaseClassClass = class of TBaseClass;

function GetDescendantClass(op: Integer): TBaseClassClass;
begun
  case op of
    1: Result := TChild1Class;
    2: Result := TChild2Class;
    else Assert(False);
  end;
end;

var
  DescendantClass: TBaseClassClass;

DescendantClass := GetDescendantClass (op);
T := DescendantClass.Create;
T.DoIt;
```

Using that technique, it's sometimes useful to make the constructor be virtual, but that's not a requirement.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but what is needed declare TBaseClassClass type?. The function GetDescendantClass cannot return direct TBaseClass?.

Comment: I already showed you it's declaration; you don't need anything more to declare it. If the return type were `TBaseClass`, then you'd have a factory function, and you'd need to return an *instance*, whereas when the return type is `TBaseClassClass` you return a *class* and create the instance later. `TBaseClassClass` is what's called a *metaclass* — look it up.